# Check whether object property exists in an array and display that objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
"employees":[  
    {"name":"Hosea", "email":"hosea@gmail.com", badge="silver"},  
    {"name":"javier", "email":"javier@gmail.com" badge="silver"},  
    {"name":"marston", "email":"marston@gmail.com" badge="Gold"} ,
    {"name":"arthur", "email":"arthur@gmail.com" badge="Gold"} 
]
```

Is there a way to loop through the array to check whether "badge" with same value exist, in the html using `ngIf` or `ngFor`?

[image: this will be the output]

The result will be like this

Comment: do you mean withe same badge value ? can you explain more ?

Comment: yes same badge value, so that i can categorize according to silver and gold

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your objects using any `groupBy` function, e.g. [this one from SO using TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64489535/1640425).

```
const groupBy = <T>(array: T[], predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => string) =>
  array.reduce((acc, value, index, array) => {
    (acc[predicate(value, index, array)] ||= []).push(value);
    return acc;
  }, {} as { [key: string]: T[] });
```

In your `component.ts`:

```
public employeesByBadge = groupBy(this.employees, e => e.badge);
```

Then you will need to utilize 2 `*ngFor` directives. The first one to iterate over each key value pair of the resulting grouping (`employeesByBadge`), as it will be an object. Then you will need another one to iterate over the employees just as you would without any grouping applied.

In your `component.html`:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of employeesByBadge | keyvalue">
  <span>{{group.key}}</span>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let employee of group.value">
    {{employee.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, but non optimal way is:

```
<div class="gold">
    <h2>Gold</h2>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <div *ngIf="item.badge === 'Gold'" class="gold">
            {{ item.name }}<br>
            {{ item.email }}
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
<div class="silver">
    <h2>Silver</h2>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <div *ngIf="item.badge === 'Silver'">
            {{ item.name }}<br>
            {{ item.email }}
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Better is make two different arrays of badges.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to achive this result :

[image]

use this function to **groupBy** any property you want

```
  groupBy(xs, key) {
    return xs.slice().reduce(function (rv, x) {
      (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
      return rv;
    }, {});
  }
```

Typescript

```
emps = [
    { name: 'Hosea', email: 'hosea@gmail.com', badge: 'silver' },
    { name: 'javier', email: 'javier@gmail.com', badge: 'silver' },
    { name: 'marston', email: 'marston@gmail.com', badge: 'Gold' },
    { name: 'arthur', email: 'arthur@gmail.com', badge: 'Gold' },
  ];
 
  groupBy(xs, key) {
    return xs.slice().reduce(function (rv, x) {
      (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
      return rv;
    }, {});
  }
```

Html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of groupBy(emps,'badge') | keyvalue">
  <ul>
    <li class="col-xs-2">{{ item.key }}
      <ul *ngFor="let item2 of item.value">
        <li>name {{item2.name}}</li>
        <li>name {{item2.email}}</li>
        <hr>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```